# Is there a way to publish an Azure Function from VS code using publish profile as we do in Visual studio?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, azure-deployment

I'm trying to publish a Node JS azure function from my VS Code. I have a publish profile file with all the credentials in it. How Can I instruct the VS code to **use the publish profile**?
I'm able to do it from the Visual studio for .Net function Apps.   If its not possible from VS code , Is there a way to publish a node js azure function using **publish profile** from Visual studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- This Publish Settings is only applies to Visual Studio IDE but not for VS Mac and VS Code as specified in this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/tutorial-import-publish-settings-azure?view=vs-2022) of Azure Functions Publish Profile.

[image]

- Visual Studio is mainly designed for .NET Core / Framework Project developments, but non-.NET Language can be compiled and debugged with the help of 3rd Party extensions in Visual Studio.

[image]

- As it is mentioned in above MS Doc & Image, the Publish Profile for .NET Core/framework applications and can be accessible in Visual Studio IDE.

Comment: Thanks @Pravallika Kothaveerannagari  for your response. I might go for a normal deployment in VS code without using the publish settings file for now.